# How to switch job interview into applying for a different role

Tags: interviewing, hiring-process, negotiation

**Backstory**: I am going to graduate from a cyber security degree and was looking into entering the field. My mum's friend who works in a fairly big company referred me to the company and I was asked to interview with them.

Through emails with my point of contact with the company, it was then I realised that the role I was interviewing for was a programming role instead of a cyber security role (The part where a laptop was required for a quick coding quiz clued me in).

To be fair, in my resume I had listed down several developer roles during my internships as a student. The thing is that I am not interested in a programming role as I realised it was not for me during my Bachelors which is why I transition into a Master in cybersec.

**Question**: How would I inform/ask whether I am able to switch roles into a role more related to my recent degree? I am fairly certain that they have a role more suited for me as it is a fairly large tech company and there are jobs for it listed there (Albeit not necessarily pure cybersec but may deal with security).

Should I email my point of contact and explain my situation before the interview, be honest with them during the interview or something else entirely?

**Note 1**: The job is listed as graduate trainee role.

**Note 2**: I am not sure whether if I have phrased the question title correctly, let me know if there is a more accurate representation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should get in touch with your point in contact and explain that you think you'd be a better fit for their other role, which is advertised, and you wonder if it's still available. They will let you know whether it's still available or not and if you can actually interview for that position.

Make sure you clearly mention the following:

- Why you prefer the security role and why it would be beneficial for the company to interview you for it instead of the programming one.
- Your intentions if that role is no longer available. Are you still interested in the programming position or it's this new security role or nothing?

The sooner you communicate this, the better. You'll save time for everyone.

Answer (score 2):

If you are only interested in cyber security jobs, and this is not one, simply call the person of contact, explain your position, and cancel the interview if necessary.

If you found an open, entry-level cyber security position on their website, ask if you can instead interview for that position.

If you haven't found such a position on their website, ask about one.

Next time, don't accept an interview for any position that you don't want. If it's not clear, ask questions so that you'll know which position it is. You'll want to be prepared for every interview. Part of that preparation requires that you know the role you would be expected to fill.